# Referencing WebKit or WebEngine in .ui file depending on Qt version

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to upgrade a Qt application from 5.3.1 to 5.7.0. The main change is the migration from WebKit to WebEngine. 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

We are not yet ready to stop using 5.3.1, so I created a preprocessor define based on the Qt version. This works well for the project file, class source, and class header. However, I don't see a way to do this in the .ui file.

The Qt version is used to define a preprocessor define in the `.pro` file:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    QT += widgets

    greaterThan(QT_MINOR_VERSION, 5) {
        QT += webengine webenginewidgets
        DEFINES += _WEBENGINE_
    } else {
        QT += webkit       webkitwidgets
    }
}
```

This works well in the `.cpp` file:

```cpp
#ifdef _WEBENGINE_
    #include <QWebEngineView>
    #include <QWebEnginePage>
    #include <QWebEngineFrame>
    #include <QWebEngineElement>
#else
    #include <QWebView>
    #include <QWebPage>
    #include <QWebFrame>
    #include <QWebElement>
#endif // _WEBENGINE_
```

These are the offending references in the `.ui` file:

```xml
<widget class="QWebView" name="webView" native="true">
...
</widget>
...
<customwidget>
 <class>QWebView</class>
 <extends>QWidget</extends>
 <header>QtWebKit/QWebView</header>
</customwidget>
```

Which results in the `ui_*.h` file:

```cpp
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
...
public:
    QWebView *webView;
```

How can I use the correct include paths and class names in the `.ui` file depending on the Qt version?

Comment: Can you just wrap your `QWebView` or `QWebEngineView` (depending on Qt version used) into a `QFrame` or `QWidget` and use that in the `.ui` file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in the `.ui` file. The usual way to solve this would be by creating your own wrapper widget, and using that in the `.ui` file.

```
class MyWebView : public QWidget
{ .... }

MyWebView::MyWebView(QObject *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
#ifdef _WEBENGINE_
    // add webengineview to layout so it takes all space
#else
    // add webview to layout so it takes all space
#endif
    ...
}
```